# AC meter By ADC timer interrupt from Nick Gammon

Tags: interrupt, atmega328, analogread, adc, analog-sampling

I want to read ADC from the pin A0 and A1. I have written in this code, however.

I took this code came from Nick Gammon

Thank You
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

this is code

```
const byte adcPin = 0;  // A0

const int MAX_RESULTS = 256;

volatile int results [MAX_RESULTS];
volatile int resultNumber;

// ADC complete ISR
ISR (ADC_vect)
  {
  if (resultNumber >= MAX_RESULTS)
    ADCSRA = 0;  // turn off ADC
  else
    results [resultNumber++] = ADC;
  }  // end of ADC_vect

EMPTY_INTERRUPT (TIMER1_COMPB_vect);

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  // reset Timer 1
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  TCCR1B = bit (CS11) | bit (WGM12);  // CTC, prescaler of 8
  TIMSK1 = bit (OCIE1B);  // WTF?
  OCR1A = 39;    
  OCR1B = 39;   // 20 uS - sampling frequency 50 kHz

  ADCSRA =  bit (ADEN) | bit (ADIE) | bit (ADIF);   // turn ADC on, want interrupt on completion
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADPS2);  // Prescaler of 16
  ADMUX = bit (REFS0) | (adcPin & 7);
  ADCSRB = bit (ADTS0) | bit (ADTS2);  // Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADATE);   // turn on automatic triggering

  // wait for buffer to fill
  while (resultNumber < MAX_RESULTS)
    { }

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RESULTS; i++)
    Serial.println (results [i]);

  }  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: Just change `ADMUX` in the ISR.

Comment: I want to read from a0 and a1, but the code read from a0 alone.

Comment: what  change ADMUX ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please improve your question.

Comment: This is code read ADC from A0  (voltage)  but I want to read ADC from A0 (voltage) and A1 (current )  I need to write code to add, however.

Comment: Please **stop repeating the question**! This question is very badly written, and hard to understand. **Repeating does not help**! Instead, read [How to ask](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), click on the _edit_ link, and take the time to write properly. You should also link to the Gammon's page from where you copied that code.

Comment: I want to read ADC from the pin A0 and A1

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted the first line is:

> ```
> const byte adcPin = 0;  // A0
> ```

To read from A1 the change is simple:

```
const byte adcPin = 1;  // A1
```

---

> i am sorry i come from thailand

Whatever country you are from does not excuse from you posting the same question many, many times.

I suggest you read the datasheet:

[ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)

Scroll down to **24.9.1 ADMUX – ADC Multiplexer Selection Register**

Answer (score 0):

You can read two analog channels like this:

```c++
int first_reading = analogRead(A0);
int second_reading = analogRead(A1);
```

If this does not fit your purpose, then your question was not asked
properly: rewrite it and clearly state your requirements. Explain why
the simple solution does not work for you.

If this *does* work for you, then stop (for now) reading advanced
tutorials, like the one where you found your code, and focus on the very
basics: the Arduino examples in the 01.Basics section, then the
03.Analog section.

Comment: i want  interrup ADC A0 and A1

Comment: i am sorry i come from thailand

Comment: I am do Meter Ac.    adcPin A0(measure Voltage) and adcPin A1(measure Current)   Thank You

Comment: this code from Nick Gammon read adcPin = A0

Answer (score 0):

```
constexpr byte  adc_mux_setting = bit(REFS0) | bit(ADLAR); // Left alligment for ADC result, so ADCH contains 8b result.

volatile uint16_t         sum_u = 0;
volatile uint16_t         sum_i = 0;
volatile uint8_t   resultNumber = 0;

// ADC complete ISR
ISR (ADC_vect) {
    if (resultNumber & 1) {
        sum_u += ADCH-(sum_u>>8);                  // 8bit resolution, something like floating average
    } else {
        sum_i += ADCH-(sum_i>>8);                  // 8bit resolution, something like floating average
    }
    ADMUX  = adc_mux_setting | (++resultNumber&1); // Expecting pins A0 and A1 (otherwise offset must be added)

    TIFR1 |= bit(OCF1B);                           // clear the flag otherwise it never starts ADC conversion (not without ISR)
                                                   // it's here because I don't want to ADC starts conversion before switching channel
}

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Start");

    // reset Timer 1
    TCCR1A  = 0;
    TCCR1B  = bit(CS11) | bit(WGM12);              // CTC, prescaler of 8
    TCNT1   = 0;
    //TIMSK1 = bit (OCIE1B);                       // it doesn't work without clearing OCF1B
    OCR1A   = 80;                                  // it never reaches 80 so it never sets interrupt flag
    OCR1B   = 79;                                  // 40 uS - sampling frequency 25kHz for both (15kHz for each)

    ADCSRA  = bit(ADEN)  | bit(ADIE) | bit (ADIF); // turn ADC on, want      interrupt on completion
    ADCSRA |= bit(ADPS2);                          // Prescaler of 16
    ADMUX   = adc_mux_setting;                     // A0 goes first
    ADCSRB  = bit(ADTS0) | bit(ADTS2);             // Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
    ADCSRA |= bit(ADATE);                          // turn on automatic triggering
}

void loop () {
    if (resultNumber == 0) {                       // print results after 128 measures for both channels 
        Serial.print(sum_u);
        Serial.print(' ');
        Serial.println(sum_i);
        while (resultNumber == 0);                 // I want to print it only once per iteration
    }
}
```